# Inaccessible server after DNS server change

Tags: domain-name-system, ip-address

After configuring a domain name to use the name server of the new server, the new server had become inaccessible (even if using the IP address). Is this normal?

Comment: You might consider providing some details as to what was literally changed - with the DNS records?

Comment: No this is not "normal". What response do you get from typing  NSlookup and the server name at the command prompt?

Comment: Do you have local access to this server? If so can you ping/check websites/other servers? If you cannot ping any other servers its probably a network issue.
have you checked the logs to see what errors are there? Is this Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 3):

To *directly* answer your question, the answer is no.

If you can't access one of your servers, even by IP address, you have a larger issue that goes outside of the scope of DNS.

Answer (score 0):

did accessing the new server by IP address work *before* the change? What makes you think it's actually up?

I figure one of two things is happening:

- Your 'new server' is an Apache virtual host and can only be accessed by name. When accessing it by IP, it doesn't know which host it's supposed to be. To check for this, put the hostname and IP into your `hosts` file.
- Your 'new server' is down. Nothing to do with your DNS change.